# Create a row where sequence of month is Missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, loops

I need a help to build Dataframe in python where if a sequence of month is missing it will create a new row with Monthly Revenue as 0. the check for sequence of Month will be till Total Age of particular VIN. Below are the Dataframes.

CurrentDf:

| VIN | Total Age | Months | Monthly Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | 10 | 00 | 1513 |
| v1 | 10 | 05 | 1108 |
| v1 | 10 | 07 | 4330 |
| v1 | 10 | 09 | 7121 |
| v2 | 08 | 01 | 1998 |
| v2 | 08 | 04 | 4997 |
| v2 | 08 | 05 | 8528 |
| v2 | 08 | 06 | 1783 |
| v2 | 08 | 07 | 9628 |
| v2 | 08 | 08 | 2082 |

OutputDf:

| VIN | Total Age | Months | Monthly Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | 10 | 00 | 1513 |
| v1 | 10 | 01 | 00 |
| v1 | 10 | 02 | 00 |
| v1 | 10 | 03 | 00 |
| v1 | 10 | 04 | 00 |
| v1 | 10 | 05 | 1108 |
| v1 | 10 | 06 | 00 |
| v1 | 10 | 07 | 433 |
| v1 | 10 | 08 | 00 |
| v1 | 10 | 09 | 7121 |
| v1 | 10 | 10 | 00 |
| V2 | 08 | 00 | 00 |
| v2 | 08 | 01 | 1998 |
| v2 | 08 | 02 | 00 |
| v2 | 08 | 03 | 00 |
| v2 | 08 | 04 | 4997 |
| v2 | 08 | 05 | 8528 |
| v2 | 08 | 06 | 1783 |
| v2 | 08 | 07 | 9628 |
| v2 | 08 | 08 | 2082 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```py
def reindexer(x):
    x = (
        x.reset_index()
        .set_index("Months")
        .reindex(range(0, x["Total Age"].max() + 1))
    )
    x["Total Age"] = x["Total Age"].ffill().bfill().astype(int)
    x["Monthly Revenue"] = x["Monthly Revenue"].fillna(0)
    return x


x = (
    df.groupby("VIN")
    .apply(reindexer)
    .drop(columns=["index", "VIN"])
    .reset_index()
)
print(x.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | VIN | Months | Total Age | Monthly Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | v1 | 0 | 10 | 1513 |
| 1 | v1 | 1 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | v1 | 2 | 10 | 0 |
| 3 | v1 | 3 | 10 | 0 |
| 4 | v1 | 4 | 10 | 0 |
| 5 | v1 | 5 | 10 | 1108 |
| 6 | v1 | 6 | 10 | 0 |
| 7 | v1 | 7 | 10 | 4330 |
| 8 | v1 | 8 | 10 | 0 |
| 9 | v1 | 9 | 10 | 7121 |
| 10 | v1 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 11 | v2 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| 12 | v2 | 1 | 8 | 1998 |
| 13 | v2 | 2 | 8 | 0 |
| 14 | v2 | 3 | 8 | 0 |
| 15 | v2 | 4 | 8 | 4997 |
| 16 | v2 | 5 | 8 | 8528 |
| 17 | v2 | 6 | 8 | 1783 |
| 18 | v2 | 7 | 8 | 9628 |
| 19 | v2 | 8 | 8 | 2082 |

---

<sup>Updated that **Months** doesn't exceed **Total Age**</sup>

Comment: here in your solution the "Month" column is exciding the "Total Age" where as my requirement is:- Month should be equal too of smaller than Total Age", can you please look again in it... @Andrej Kesely

Comment: @Ninja See my update.

Comment: thanks for the solution can you please help me to get the output in dataframe?

Comment: @Ninja Yes, do `print(x)` and it will print the dataframe. Do `x.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)` and it will save it to CSV file